# how to use nested result set in jdbc

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, jdbc

i want to retrieve categories and its associated subcategories from database in the the following format as shown in image....![KIDS menu where shop, help, mycompany, account, popular are categories and labels inside them are subcategories][1]

i have written following code

```
<li class="active grid"><a class="color3" href="#">KIDS</a>
<div class="megapanel">
<div class="row">
<div class="col1">
<div class="h_nav">
<%
try 
{
String sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE Cat_Label='KIDS'";   
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) 
{
int catid;
String catname;
catid=rs.getInt(1);
  catname=rs.getString(3);
%>
<h4><%=catname%></h4>
<%
String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE Cat_Id='"+catid+"'"; 
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(sql1);
while (rs1.next()) 
{
String subcatnm;
subcatnm=rs1.getString(3);
%>
<ul>
<li><a href=""><%=subcatnm%></a></li>
</ul>                                       
<%}
rs1.close();
}
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
}
catch (SQLException e) 
{}
catch (Exception e) 
{}
%>
</div>                          
</div>
<div class="col1">
<div class="h_nav">
<img src="images/kids.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

this code retrieves only first category and its associated subcategories...
the first resultset get closed..when control goes to second resultset

now tell me what should i have to do to get all the categories and its associated subcategories

can i do this by using another way like subquery or anything else

plzz suggest me the answer
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it would really help if you gather the data first - a Map > and render your html. Mixing logic and display will end up confusing you.

Move the rs.close() statement outside the outer while loop.

Comment: can i do this by using sub query?

Comment: Yes, you can. But now you will need another piece of logic to print out the main category. Better you create a Map of K=String (categories), V=List of String(subcategories)